# PDO count records in db with in the current date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to count the newly register members but I'm having trouble

```
  $time = new DateTime();
    $currentdate = $time->format('Y-m-d');


    $cmd=$con->query("select count(*) from user where date(datereg) = ?");
    $cmd->execute($currentdate);
    $rowcount = $cmd->fetchColumn();

     echo $rowcount;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't just use NOW() function in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a placeholder inside your query doesn't make sense since you're not preparing it.

```
$cmd=$con->query("select count(*) from user where date(datereg) = ?");
         // ^ query not prepare

$cmd->execute($currentdate); // execute? $cmd is not prepared
```

Just create a normal query inside it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM user WHERE DATE(datereg) = CURDATE()';
$result = $con->query($sql);
$count = $result->fetchColumn();
```